# Regex.Replace without destroying the content of Word Document (like Footnote)

Tags: .net, regex, replace, ms-word, interop

I have a Regex.Replace inside this method `RegexReplace` that is used like

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Range().Text = 
   Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Range().Text.RegexReplace()
```

However, as you may be able to imagine, because I am directly dealing with Text, the control characters gets destroyed.

Is there any good way to deal with this problem?

EDIT : I am aware that word has native find and replace (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1f367bx.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), However, I am looking for the ability for positive lookahead. So this route was not the most optimal (if I just do not know how to do wildcard positive lookahead, I would like to know how to)

Example of positive lookahead using regex is following.

```
public static string RegexReplace(this string input)
{
       var goalRegEx = new Regex(@"(" + UnicodeLeftSingleQuotation + @"(?=\d{3}(\.|,|\s){1}))"); 
       // positive lookahead. limits to 3 digits. 
       //no more no less. but not inclusive

       // word has find and replace feature that allows to use wildcard using 
       //--- ‘[0-9]{3}[^11-^14^t.^s]{1} --- 
       //however they do not have ability to do positive lookahead.
       return goalRegEx.Replace(input, UnicodeRightSingleQuotation);
}
```

In above code `(?=\d{3}(\.|,|\s){1})` indicates that I want to find 3 digits followed by space or comma or period but not include them in the search result (so in this case I am trying to replace only the left single quotation mark.

EDIT2 :

So After learning about expression capability, I tried using it to find and replace using Word native Find and Replace (Short cut key Ctrl+H) With expression `"‘([0-9]{3}>)"`. However below code does not seemed to work as I intended it to.

```
    With find
        .ClearFormatting()
        .Text = "‘([0-9]{3}>)"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting()
        .Replacement.Text = "’\1"
        .Execute(Replace:=WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, MatchWildcards:=True)
    End With
```

I applied it to a string and had no luck

```
‘123 Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
This line contains a patent quote '123 abbreviation that does not need to be changed.  It uses a straight quote.
This line contains a properly formatted patent quote abbreviation ’123. This is what we want to see.
```

EDIT 3 : Seems like AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes and AutoFormatReplaceQuotes has to be set to False in order to update using the Find.

Comment: Use Word's built-in Range.Find and Replace functionality instead of RegEx. There are tons of examples and explanations "out there", like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747856/replace-part-of-word-footer-text-without-losing-formatting-and-active-objects/33761565#33761565 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716746/vba-ms-word-is-it-possible-to-replace-text-with-wildcard/34725839#34725839

Comment: I have used that approach with help of microsoft document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1f367bx.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 but I found out that word wildcard does not have positive lookahead which I would like to have for my search and replace.

Comment: Don't expect Word people to know what a "wildcard positive lookahead" is. Best would be to include an example of text and explanation of what you want.

Comment: Yes, Word wildcards can do this. That's exactly the topic of the second link I provided in my original comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am now able to replace the strings using wildcard in word find and replace. However I cannot replace them using the code. I am using `"‘([0-9]{3}>)"` as Find.Text and `"’\1"` as Replacement.Text. For execution, I am assigning replace as wdReplaceAll and MatchWildcards as True. Do you see any possible issue with how I am utilizing it?

Comment: Could you please use the [edit] link below your question to supplement it with the code you've tried as well as sample text with what the search string should find and with what it should be replaced?

Comment: I thought it would solve the issue with above code but all of the quotes remains the same (second quotes are suppose to remain the same as it is straight quotes)

Comment: Given you third edit, about AutoFormatAsYouType: Are you OK now?

Comment: Yup! Thank you very much for thorough assistance! :)